# ES6 override parent method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm currently customizing a react nuka-carousel https://github.com/kenwheeler/nuka-carousel. I want to override getDecoratorStyles method in carousel.js. The class looks like this:

```
const Carousel = React.createClass({
...
  render() {
  ...
            return (
              <div
                style={assign(self.getDecoratorStyles(Decorator.position), Decorator.style || {})}
                className={'slider-decorator-' + index}
                key={index}>
                <Decorator.component
...
  getDecoratorStyles(position) {
    switch (position) {
      case 'TopLeft': {
        return {
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        }
 ...
```

I tried to extend the class and override the method but it seems to have no effect :(

```
...
import NukaCarousel from 'nuka-carousel';
...
class MXCarousel extends NukaCarousel {
    getDecoratorStyles(position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 'CenterLeft':
            return {
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 1000,
                left: 0,
                transform: 'translateY(-50%)',
                WebkitTransform: 'translateY(-50%)'
            };
        case 'CenterRight':
            return {
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 990,
                right: 0,
                transform: 'translateY(-50%)',
                WebkitTransform: 'translateY(-50%)'
            };
        default:
            return super.getDecoratorStyles(position);
        }
    }
}

export default class Carousel extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const sliderSettings =
        { cellSpacing: 30, slidesToShow: 6, slideWidth: '100px' };

        return (
            <MXCarousel decorators = {decorators} {...sliderSettings} className="component-carousel">
...
```

Do I have an error in my es6 understanding? is the method not overidden when called in parent class?

Comment: It should work. Make sure you're working on the instance of the class you actually want. Also if you're using a transpiler make sure they fully support what you need, although I would have expected overriding to already be on the list...

Comment: it doesn't work :( we use webpack and babel, but I'm bad in configurating this stuff and other things work

Comment: what is the `decorators` variable which you are passing to `MXCarousel`'s props?

Comment: I have decorators for prev and next buttons, similar to default decorators

Comment: Are those decorators for positions `CenterRight` and `CenterLeft`?

Comment: good point, they were. now it's changed, so I need to check again, but when I first implemented it I'm pretty sure, that it didn't work with correct positions

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that `decorators` variable you are passing to carousel props may override the styles from `getDecoratorStyles` method.
Decorators passed to props in `Carousel` class are mapped to elements in `render` method.
Particularly notice the line where the styles are assigned to element:

```
style={assign(self.getDecoratorStyles(Decorator.position), Decorator.style || {})}
```

The consequence is that if related decorator contains it's own styles then styles generated by `getDecoratorStyles` method can be overriden.

Comment: Please check your `decorators` and attach it to the answer if this does not solve the issue